# How to delete header and footer of pdf in xpdf

Tags: pdf, xpdf

As the  Title said,I get the data of **PDF** in **xpdf(pdftotext)**,but it contains header and footer.Now I want to delete both of header and footer.How to make it ? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

How to Delete a Header or Footer

To delete header or footer information, you’ll initially need to ‘show’ Infix PDF Editor the position of the data you want to remove. It will then extrapolate this across the entire document.

You’ll select the header or footer using the Object (arrow) tool Then, click the header data , Creating this selection gives Infix PDF Editor the coordinates of the item you want to remove.

Then, in the Edit menu, click Delete Across Pages. In the dialog box that opens, you can choose whether to delete on all pages, selected pages, or odd/ even pages only.

Comment: Are there any methods to do it by processing? Program to make it